# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied jupyter kernel

Tags: python, jupyter

I installed a new python 64 bit in my program files folder. I changed my jupyter kernel file in AppData/Roaming/Jupyter/kernels/kernel.json to take this new python as the python. 
the kernel. JSON is

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:/Program Files/Python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "python 3.7 64 bit",
 "language": "python"
}
```

The error when I open a new notebook is PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
What should I change to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your operating system is not allowing to edit your file. Try open your notebook in administrator mode.

1. Right click on file
2. Open as administrator
3. make changes.

try this I hope your problem will be solved.